# Lua table length function override not working

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

How does one change the length operator (`#`) for a table in Lua, the manual suggests assigning the `__len` function in a metatable and then assigning that metatable to the table I want to override, but this doesn't work as expected? I do not have the option to override this on the C side.

```
turtles = {1,2,3}
setmetatable(turtles, {__len = function(mytable) return 5 end})

print(#turtles)
--returns 3, should return 5
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua override # for strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085204/lua-override-for-strings)

Comment: @LarryBattle Not really a duplicate, here the operand is not a string, but a table.

Comment: Your code works fine in the [Lua live demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be using Lua 5.1. The `__len` metamethod on tables is supported since Lua 5.2.

In [Lua 5.1 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8), if the operand is a table, return the primitive table length directly.

> "len": the # operation.
>
> ```
> function len_event (op)
>    if type(op) == "string" then
>      return strlen(op)         -- primitive string length
>    elseif type(op) == "table" then
>      return #op                -- primitive table length
>    else
>      local h = metatable(op).__len
>      if h then
>        -- call the handler with the operand
>        return (h(op))
>      else  -- no handler available: default behavior
>        error(···)
>      end
>    end
>  end
> ```

In [Lua 5.2 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4),  if the operand is a table, check if the `__len` metamethod is available.

> "len": the # operation.
>
> ```
> function len_event (op)
>    if type(op) == "string" then
>      return strlen(op)      -- primitive string length
>    else
>      local h = metatable(op).__len
>      if h then
>        return (h(op))       -- call handler with the operand
>      elseif type(op) == "table" then
>        return #op              -- primitive table length
>      else  -- no handler available: error
>        error(···)
>      end
>    end
>  end
> ```

Comment: In the Lua 5.1 reference code as you've shown there, it clearly extracts the metatable and looks for the metamethod `__len`, then calls said metamethod `h` on the original table `op`. What doesn't make sense though is that code will never get executed, because `elseif type(op) == "table"` will always evaluate to `true` (since only tables can have metatables. The code below in the `else` cannot ever be executed. In other words: the code for this is there but the function seems to be written improperly.

Comment: Tables are not the only values that have metatables in Lua. All values can have an associated metatable. In particular, the `else` clause in the Lua 5.1 reference quoted above is frequently used to implement the `#` operator for userdata.